# Raise notice from PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function that updates several tables.  As an example, let's say it does something similar to:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = some_value;
UPDATE boo SET far = another_value;
```

I would like to be able to see how many records are updated in each table.  I know that I can display information with a Raise Notice, but don't know how to get the number of records updated by each statement.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: By curiosity, my answer is not what you wanted?

Comment: I just haven't had time to test it yet. I like to full test answer before flagging one as correct.  Did you down vote me because I haven't given you your points, yet? Seriously?

Comment: I put the comment, you connected and don't deign to answer. It was when you got a down vote when you entered the rush. I hope the answer will serve you, I don't need you give me points, save it for others answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

[GET DIAGNOSTICS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

For example (in your function):

```
...
sql := 'UPDATE foo SET bar = some_value';
EXECUTE sql;
GET DIAGNOSTICS rowsAffected = ROW_COUNT;
...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works.  However, it should be noted that the variable "rowsAffected" must be included in the declare section.  I declared it as an INT and it works fines for my purposes.